# org.springframework.boot hotdeploy does not work at gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

As we know `org.springframework.boot` support hot deploy to detect any changes 
without restart application.

It  works with maven when I run it with `mvn spring-boot:run`
but it does not work when I run it with `gradle bootRun`, it does not detect property file change automatically .

in my `build.gradle` i defined it already.

any hints will be more than welcome!

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to configure `bootRun` to load resources from `src/main/resources` rather than their built location beneath `build`. You can do so with the following configuration:

```
bootRun {
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
}
```

Alternatively, you could use Gradle's continuous build support so that any changes in `src/main/resources` or `src/main/java` are automatically detected and then built. DevTools will then notice the changes in the build's output and reload.